# Xcode skips tests when module stability is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm building a dynamic library that has BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION turned on for module stability. I have a class which is a basic property wrapper that uses generics that is public. When I add this class to a test class and run the tests the XCTestCase class that refers to this class doesn't run (all others do). I'm able to run the test by triggering it from the diamond shape next to the test case.

- When I change the struct to be internal the tests run normally with cmd+u.
- Setting BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = NO also lets the tests run normally.
- Removing reference to the struct from the test also get them running.
- I'm using iOS 10 as minimum deployment target and setting this to be iOS 13 (for the tests) also somehow gets the tests running.

Have any of you encountered this weird bug with Xcode and know of any other solution? I've tested this on 11.5 as well as 11.3.1 and the behaviour is the same.

```
@propertyWrapper
public struct Wrapper<T: Codable> {
    ...

    public var wrappedValue: T? {
        get {...}
        set {...}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was caused by public structs that use generics while BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES. Either marking the struct as @frozen or changing it to a class type solves the issue.